# Selenium Java Script Webdriver using Mocha - take screenshot if test fails

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Using Selenium webdriver (Java Script) and Mocha

```
var assert = require('assert'),
test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
until = require('selenium-webdriver').until,
webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
```

If test fails, I want to take a screen shot using after function from Mocha:

```
    function writeScreenshot(data, name) {
        name = name || 'ss.png';

        var screenshotPath = '/result/';

        fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
    };

    afterEach(function () {
        if (this.currentTest.state == 'failed') {
            console.log("If condition");
            driver.takeScreenshot().then(function (data) {
                writeScreenshot(data, 'failed.png');
            });
        }
    });
```

After running the test, if condition returned true. But it does not create a screenshot.

Comment: Had to wait for the screenshot to finish. Below code fixed it.                                                                                                               return driver.takeScreenshot().then(function (data) {
                writeScreenshot(data, 'failed.png');

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/269#issuecomment-306342170 - use `afterTest` and `browser.saveScreenshot` if `!test.passed` in `wdio.conf.js`

Comment: There is nothing about webdriverio in the question.